# Connect MATLAB to cartoDB using Database Explorer?

Tags: postgresql, carto, database, matlab

I set up a database on cartoDB.

I'm trying to use MATLAB to connect to the database using Database Explorer. I've downloaded the PostgreSQL driver.

MATLAB asks for connection Parameters:

Server Name
Port Number
Username
Password
Database

What specific information should be in these fields to connect MATLAB to my database. I'm pretty sure the username and password I have covered, but not the other 3.

Comment: Hey James, have you taken a look at this: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/postgresql-jdbc-windows.html. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB doesn't support direct connections to user databases, so you'd need to use our SQL API in order to connect both: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html